# Dynamic Data Template Selecting in Silverlight for wp7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a list of different types of elements. I would like to display a different data template for different list elements, based on what type it is. I have found a bunch of examples of how to do this online, but they look ridiculously complex and error prone. Is there a more elegant way?

http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/11/silverlight-data-template-selector.html

http://dotnet-redzone.blogspot.com/2010/05/datatemplate-selector-with-silverlight.html

http://blog.geeky.cc/post/2009/09/11/Silverlight-DataTemplateSelector.aspx

I'm developing for Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 0):

Those examples for the most part appear to be just what you need. If you are looking for a more packaged approach there is one available on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLTemplateSelector.aspx).

One reason is may feel overly complex or perhaps requiring large amount of code for something that appears trivial is that Silverlight does not contain a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class as does WPF.

Either way the [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLTemplateSelector.aspx) offering or one of the offerings you posted (ignoring the one geared at MEF unless you are making use of MEF) should suffice in giving you what you need.